# Function which counts multiplies chars in a String

Tags: java

For my Homework I need to count chars in a `String`. If there are more than three of the same char behind each other the method schould return `true` if not `false`.

Now develop a method `noMultiples ()`, which checks if there are three (or more) equal characters in a string
Generalize `noMultiples ()` now,that the number of characters to be repeated is parameterized.

I alredy tried to spilt the `String` in to substrings but received an `String index out of Bounds` error. Also i tried to work with the `charAt()` method but I am kinda stuck now. Are there any ways to solve this problem ?
Thanks in advance

```
 public static boolean noMultiples(int n, String s) {
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        if(s.charAt(i)==s.charAt(i+1)&&s.charAt(i+1)==s.charAt(i+2)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This should be the expected output :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean result = noMultiples("Hello World");
    System.out.println(result); // => true
    System.out.println(noMultiples("faaantastic")); // => false
    System.out.println(noMultiples(2, "Hello World")); // => false
}
```

Comment: where is your noMultiples function code?

Comment: `String.charAt` is a good starting point. Then, you can create an array (`int[26]`) in order to count the occurrence of each character then parse the `String`. For each character, increment the corresponding cell of the array. If one of the cells reaches `3`, return `true`. Otherwise, return `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use some field inside the method to store the amount of char repetitions.

Also, [overload](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) `noMultiples` to accept only the string.

**Note**: since `noMultiples` return `true` if it found multiple consecutive chars, it's better to name this method `containsMultiples`. By doing so it will be more intuitive in the future, where you will modify or use it later.

```
public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(containsMultiples("Hello World"));
        System.out.println(containsMultiples("faaaantastic"));
        System.out.println(containsMultiples(2, "Hello World"));
    }

    public static boolean containsMultiples(int n, String s) {
        int len = s.length();
        if(len == 0) return false;
        char lastChar = s.charAt(0);
        int multipliesFound = 1;

        for(int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
            if(s.charAt(i) == lastChar) {
                multipliesFound++;
            }
            else {
                multipliesFound = 1;
            }
            if(multipliesFound == n) {
                return true;
            }
            lastChar = s.charAt(i);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean containsMultiples(String s) {
        return containsMultiples(3, s);
    }
}
```

returns:

```
false
true
true
```

Based on your examples for the `Hello World` string, I assumed you're looking for a method to find only consecutive equals chars.

Comment: The name from the Methode is given by the Task also the task is reviwed automatically.
Thanks for your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to create a `HashMap` for character and integer pairs, and put the characters and their count in it!

```
public boolean noMultiples(int maxMultiples, String myString) {
    HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i=0; i<myString.length(); i++) {
        char c = myString.charAt(i);
        if(map.containsKey(c)) {
           int prevCount = map.get(c);
           map.put(c, prevCount+1); //we found one more of this character
        } else {
           map.put(c, 1); //first occurence
        }
    }
    //here our map is filled with characters and their count in the string
    for(int charCount: map.values()) {
       if(charCount >= maxMultiples) return false; //found a multiple
    }
    return true; //not found a large enough multiple
}
```

This could be optimized a bit by returning `false` from the first loop if we encounter a large enough value there, but this way the filled hash map can be used to further generalize the method.

Comment: `noMultiples( 3, "blabb" );` should return `true` (I have overseen the `consecutive` for the occurrences too)

Comment: No, the way I understand it should return false. The parameter 3 means that if if a character repeats 3 or more times that should be a 'multiple'. 'b' clearly repeats 3 times in 'blabb' , so there is a 'multiple' and the method NO MULTIPLES returns false.

Comment: Yes. The whole question is quite misleading. _If there are more than three of the same char behind each other…_ instead of correctly asked: _is containing three or more equal characters…_ So I have relied on Dalaro's example. If You take a look at my solutions – I first solved the simple _is-containinig-three-or-more-chars_-problem with a lambda `s.codePoints().distinct().allMatch()` one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

*shorter is a solution with lambda*

```
public static boolean noMultiples(int n, String s) {
  return s.codePoints().distinct().allMatch( c -> {
    int from = 0;
    while( (from = s.indexOf( c, from )) >= 0 ) {
      for( int i = from, count = 1; i < s.length() && c == s.charAt( i ); i++ ) {
        if( count++ >= n )
          return( false );
      }
      from++;
    }
    return( true );
  } );
}
```

find all distinct characters of `String` **s** first
then check if the number of all *consecutive* occurrences is less than **n**
faster would be to check the opposite – are there any multiples – if time plays a role